# modx и ошибка 503

Tags: modx, хостинг

Делаю перенос сайта modx с денвера на домен. Однако после переноса выдает ошибку 503. Помогите ее решить. Если входить в раздел менеджера, то там просто пустой экран, где ничего нет по сути.

Если говорить про ядро core, то там в логах нет никаких данных, так как в процессе переноса были затерты логи. Изучая .htaccess тоже могу сказать, что там нет никаких запрещенных секций.

Comment: смотрите логи web сервера, php и modx, если есть ошибка то где-то в логах должны быть записи

Comment: хорошо, спасибо за совет.

Answer (score 1):

503 значит что явно не всё в порядке с путями в конфигах. Вот тебе 4 файла -

```
/config.core.php
/connectors/config.core.php
/manager/config.core.php
/core/config/config.inc.php
```

Проверь в них все пути и особенно в последнем - в нём так же содержатся доступы к базе данных - они тоже должны быть изменены. Если всё сделал правильно - то должно заработать.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы наиболее безболезненно перенести сайт modx на хостинг нужно сделать следующие пункты:

1. Очищаем кэш в MODX (**Управление -> очистить кэш**)
2. Теперь идем в **Управление -> Завершить все сеансы**
3. Заходим через файл-менеджер к себе на сервер в папку `/core/cache` и удаляем все папки которые там есть
4. **Обязательно** делаем копии всех файлов и базы данных сайта на MODX Revo. Если сайт у вас на локальном компьютере, просто сделайте копию папки с файлами сайта и экспорт базы данных в *phpMyAdmin* в формате SQL
5. Закачиваем файлы на хостинг
6. Переносим базу данных на хостинг путём импорта
7. Открываем файлы:

   `/core/config/config.inc.php
   /config.core.php
   /connectors/config.core.php
   /manager/config.core.php`

   С помощью редактора Notepade или другого любого html редактора заменяем старое имя MySQL сервера на новый (всего localhost), так же везде заменяем имя базы данных и пароль.

   Также везде заменяем старые пути на новые. Обратите внимание на то, что пути к сайту указываются от корня сервера, а не домена. Например:

   было:

   `$modx_core_path= '/home/oldsite/public_html/core/';`

   стало:

   `$modx_core_path= '/www/newsite/core/';`

Вот и все! Сайт должен заработать!